# javascript eventlistener not working for ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addeventlistener

Hello I have loaded div via ajax and wanted to give javascript eventlistener with addEventListener method but this not working. Here below is my code

```
var QuantityMiniCart = function() {
      var infor = document.querySelectorAll( '.mini-cart-product-infor' );
      if ( ! infor.length ) {
       return;
      }
   };
      (function () {
       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function () {
          QuantityMiniCart();
       })
      })();
    infor.forEach(
    function( ele, i ) {
       
            input       = ele.querySelector( 'input.qty' ),
            
        }

        // Check valid quantity.
        input.addEventListener(
            'change',
            function() {
            }
        );
    }
);
```

here is ajax code

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: add_mini_cart_ajax.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action : 'mode_theme_update_mini_cart'
                },
                success: function( response ) {
                    $('.confirm-product').html(response);

                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    return;
                }

            });
```

The .confirm-product containing .mini-cart-product-infor which is loading from ajax. Please help for this

Comment: This is probably because you assigned these event listeners before the AJAX loaded elements are actually rendered. Read about how [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) can help you solve this.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` can only select elements which exist at the time that command is run. It can't do anything which elements which don't exist yet!

So if you're loading more content via AJAX, after you've run the code shown in your question, then you'll need to separately add event listeners to any newly-downloaded elements, once the AJAX call is complete.

Comment: can you give me solution for this please with this code?

Comment: which part of what I suggested are you struggling with? You already know (because I can see it in your code), how to select elements and add event listeners to them. So I'm a little unsure what it is you need an example of.

Comment: how can i added event listeners after ajax load at ajax sucesss

Comment: Inside the "success" function, write some code which attaches event listeners to the elements you want, after you've added them to the page. Or, from that function, make a call to another function which does the job. It's basically the same process as you've already written code for, you're just running it from a different place.